# Find a common word

Tags: word, tribond

Can you find a word that can be directly associated with each of the following words:

> Queen
>
> Letter
>
> Thermometer

Comment: I think 'tribond' tag is applicable too.

Comment: This is silly but how about 'My Queen', My 'Letter' and 'My Thermometer' :)

Comment: @humn: This is hardly the first riddle on this site that has received multiple, plausible answers.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

A word:

> Mercury

Queen:

> Queen is a rock band. One of the members is Freddie Mercury.

Letter:

> Mercury is the Roman god of messages and communication (and hence, letters). (I'm not completely satisfied with this one, but it works.)

Thermometer:

> Many thermometers are (were? I'm not sure if they still are) made with mercury in them.

Answer (score 6):

Answer:

> red

Queen

> A deck of cards contains four queens,
> including the Queen of Hearts
> (who was a character in [*Alice's Adventures in Wonderland*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queen_of_Hearts_(Alice%27s_Adventures_in_Wonderland)))
> and the Queen of Diamonds — both of which are red.
> Also, [*Through the Looking-Glass*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Queen_(Through_the_Looking-Glass)) features a (different) character
> called the Red Queen.

Letter

> "Red letter day" is an idiom meaning a special day, or a holiday.

Thermometer

> Thermometers often contain alcohol with red dye for visibility.

Comment: +1. Funnily enough, _black_ could work just as well.

Comment: This (and Will's suggestion) was my first thought, but I didn't submit it as an answer because I wasn't sure if, by "directly associated", it meant what those words normally mean, or it meant "a common phrase is made by combining the words"

Answer (score 5):

Is it

> Fahrenheit

Queen

> a [song](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qSSPs-ZtA3I) sung by Mr. Fahrenheit(stage name)

Letter

> letter F is used as a unit symbol for temperature

Thermometer

> a unit used for measuring temperature in thermometers.

Comment: Queen is the name of the band dude

Answer (score 1):

Could it be:

> Stamp

Queen

> appears on UK **stamps**

Letter

> needs a **stamp**

Thermometer

> **stamp** thermometers (record a min/max)

Answer (score 0):

Word:

> Reading

Queen:

> Reading is a Town in England, which was/is under the Queen of England , and from this [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reading,_Berkshire) page of Reading I found a motto: With God and Queen.

Letter:

> you can read a letter.

Thermometer:

> you have to take the readings from the thermometer.